# How to use Injector from Provider Factory

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

In my Angular 2 app, I have a requirement where I need to register one of two derived types for a given base type at run-time. I came up with this:

In my module, I use a Provider Factory. The constructor of ApiService needs the angular Http service and my own ConfigService, so that's what the deps property is for.

```
// imports omitted

let appContentBranchValue = 'myApp';

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
    imports: [ ... ],
    providers: [
        { provide: 'AppContentBranch', useValue: appContentBranchValue },
        { provide: ApiService,
          deps: [Http, ConfigService],
          useFactory: ApiServiceProviderFactory.create(appContentBranchValue) },
    ]
})
export class MyAccountModule { }
```

In my TypeScript service class, before the definition of ApiService and its derived types, I have this Provider Factory implementation.

I put the implementation here mainly to keep the logic of how to choose between ApiServiceMock and ApiServiceReal out of the module. If a certain localStorage key exists and has a truthy value, the factory creates and returns ApiServiceMock otherwise ApiServiceReal.

```
export class ApiServiceProviderFactory {
    public static create = (appContentBranch: string) => {
        let factory = (http: Http, configService: ConfigService): ApiService => {

            let flagKey = appContentBranch + '.mock.api';
            let flagValue = localStorage.getItem(flagKey);

            if (flagValue && JSON.parse(flagValue)) {
                return new ApiServiceMock(http, configService);
            } else {
                return new ApiServiceReal(http, configService);
            }
        };
        return factory;
    };
}
```

Instead of passing Http and ConfigService into my factory function, is it possible to instead pass the Injector like this?

```
        let factory = (injector: InjectorOfSomeKind): ApiService => {

            let flagKey = appContentBranch + '.mock.api';
            let flagValue = localStorage.getItem(flagKey);

            if (flagValue && JSON.parse(flagValue)) {
                return injector.get(ApiServiceMock);
            } else {
                return injector.get(ApiServiceReal);
            }
        };
        return factory;
    };
}
```

If I could do this, then the dirty business of how to call the constructor can be avoided entirely.

Can this be done? Regards, Ian.

Comment: what does `InjectorOfSomeKind` mean?.

Comment: OK, I meant Injector from angular/core.

Answer (score 4):

I came across similar need and i was able to inject the Injector dependency as part of deps

```js
const cookieServiceFactory = (platformId: Object, injector: Injector) => {
  return isPlatformBrowser(platformId)
    ? injector.get(BrowserCookieService)
    : injector.get(ServerCookieService);
};
```

And registered as below

```js
providers: [
  {
    provide: 'cookieFactory',
    useFacory: cookieServiceFactory,
    deps: [PLATFORM_ID, Injector]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just inject `injector:Injector` and then use `injector.get(ApiService)`.

For testing you can use

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [{provide: ApiService, useClass: ApiServiceMock}]   
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to inject a different instance of `ApiService` at run-time depending on the value of a retrieved local storage key which name is based on a constant value.

---

To inject the right implementation based on your desired criteria, create a factory function and specify the required dependencies as function parameters. Then in the module definition, use `deps` property when declaring the provider and pass the dependencies to the function parameters.

That's it! Now your factory function simply need to return the right implementation based on your conditions.

**MyAccountModule**

```js
const appContentBranch = 'myApp';

function apiServiceFactory(http: HttpClient, configService: ConfigService): ApiService {
  // retrieve key from LocalStorage
  const useMockApi = localStorage.getItem(`${appContentBranch}.mock.api`);

  // if key is present and its value is true
  if (useMockApi && JSON.parse(useMockApi)) {
    return new ApiServiceMock(http, configService);
  }
  // otherwise return real api
  return new ApiServiceReal(http, configService);
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    HttpClientModule,
  ]
  providers: [
    ConfigService,
    {
      provide: ApiService,
      useFactory: apiServiceFactory,
      deps: [HttpClient, ConfigService],
    },
  ]
})
export class MyAccountModule { }
```

**ApiService**

```js
export abstract class ApiService {
  // define methods to implement
  // it needs to be an abstract class instead of an interface
  // so that it can be used as an injection token
}
```

**ApiServiceMock**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ApiServiceMock implements ApiService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private configService: ConfigService,
  ) { }
}
```

**ApiServiceReal**

```js
@Injectable()
export class ApiServiceReal implements ApiService {
  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
    private configService: ConfigService,
  ) { }
}
```

> **Stackblitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stackoverflow-41029733**
>   Change the value of `useMockApi` property in `app.module.ts` to test returned message declared in each implementation of the `ApiService`